# SEITR model formulation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I would like to formulate a SEITR model with infectivity in the exposed period and treatment.
What I did is something like this:
\begin{align*}
    S'&= -bS(I+eE+dT)\\
    E' &= bS(I+eE+dT) -(a+c)E\\
    I' &= aE - kI\\
    T'&= cE -nT\\
    R'&= kI +nT\\
\end{align*}
Is this valid?